# How to check whether someone changed the entity data

Tags: python, google-app-engine

For example, All "Transaction Table" entities editable for all the users. How can i check, Is someone changed and updated the same entity ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly you want to make sure that if two people are editing the same entity, one of them shouldn't be able save.

First of all it's a good idea to have this Base class for all your models with these two properties that are being updated automatically:

```
class Base(ndb.Model):
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Now having the `modified` property in your model helps a lot on noticing if something was changed (by someone else) during the update:

- Before editing read the `modified` property and store it in `before_modified`
- Before saving read the `modified` property and compare it with `before_modified`
- If these two values are the same then it's safe to save, otherwise notify the user that this entity has been changed by someone else

Comment: Good Suggestion. Thanks @Lipis. One more thing i want to make sure that, Does the user has changed any of the data in the entity or they just pressed the save button. ie, "Transaction" have around 33 properties.It is a Long html form. and if user send a post request it is just saving to the entity without checking whether user has changed the data or not. Is there any way to check this without checking the individually ?

Comment: @Rookie You can do all sort of smart things to make the process easier.. but in the end.. you will have to check which of these 33 properties were changed (if at all) before saving.. or letting know the user which ones were changed. It really depends how you want to achieve that. You can get the list of all properties from `Transaction._properties` to start with.

Comment: Alternate strategy can be to create a lock record (with the current user as a propery) as a child of the record in question.  The if you can write the record you know the current user has the lock.  Include a time created, so you can discard stale locks.  This way no-one else could change the entity whilst the user is modifying it. Remember looking at timestamps will require to reads.  One to get the entity originally, 2nd read to fetch just before you write to check the current timestamp,  then write and in theory someone could squeeze in between the 2nd read and the write.

Answer (score 0):

Use timestamps. If the timestamp of the object you're writing doesn't match the timestamp the object had when you read it, it has been modified meanwhile.